# How to correctly show data requested from the server on the client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, react-router

When I do this on the server:

```
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  console.log("a get request");
  var tryFetch = { myString: "I am working fetch" };
  res.json(tryFetch);
});
```

and on the client:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounting...");
    const response = await fetch("/users");
    console.log(response, "res");
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    console.log(responseJson, "this is the data....");
  }
```

scenario A) at `/` the browser is console.logging the correct thing but at `/users` it is showing the json in the browser body itself. why?

scenario B)

I do this instead on the server

```
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  console.log("a get request");
  var getData = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  var response = await getData.json();
  console.log(response, "the response");
  res.send(json);
});
```

I am getting the correct response of users sent to the server but the request seems to be taking ages to fulfil and it's timing out in postman. I cant see the response logged in the browser. but it's definitely correct on the server

my main question being: am I correctly making a request on the server? and how do I get it to show on the client (without it timing out)?

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is in the server 
You're using `res.send(json)` here :

```
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  console.log("a get request");
  var getData = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  var response = await getData.json();
  console.log(response, "the response");
  res.send(json); // <---
});
```

What it basically does is send back 'json' to the client and the client side just renders it. Instead use `res.json()` to send the json as reply to the client.
So what you want is :

```
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
      console.log("a get request");
      var getData = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      var response = await getData.json();
      console.log(response, "the response");
      res.json(response); 
    });
```

Comment: ah ok, nice one! what Im slightly still confused at is that this sends it straight to the client and then it renders in the browser. how would I send it to the client but then instead of displaying it instantly, doing something with it in the client. e.g. storing it in component state and then deciding how to do display it? is that possible?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use await async for this ?

Comment: why would I not? I need to wait for the fetch to happen and then when it does, send it to the client...no?

Comment: Here I've created an example, this is the conventional way of doing it : (https://codeshare.io/2WABed)

Comment: ok cool yeh I get how to do that (I would probably use axios but yeh). just wondering how I can get it from the server to the client in the first place? coz currently it's rendering it in the browser which is not quite what I want from the server...

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more ?

Comment: also your example you are grabbing it straight from the api url, not from the server??

Comment: sure. I want to make a request on the server like fetch(url) and then send that to the client from the server. I know on the client I can also directly call fetch/axios etc to make the request but I would like to do it from the server and send it to the client state. is this even possible?? seems like now im making the request from the server and then displaying straight into the client. does that make sense?

Comment: (https://codeshare.io/2WABed) I've update it. Please check again. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: yeh this is almost perfect. the only thing it's still doing is at `/users` it's still showing me the json inside the browser window. I want that window empty until I update it in the client. does that make sense? Almost there!

Comment: For that you have to create a new component for /users route using ( refer react-router ) and request the json using that component.

Comment: ok yep, I have done that and in the Users component I make the call to `/users` still no luck though :(

Comment: if you're using /users route for a new component, then don't use the same route for fetching data from the server. Instead create a new route like '/fetchusers' and change the app.get() to `app.get('\fetchusers', `

Comment: ok so now I have: `<Route path="/users" component={Users} />` and then in the server: `app.get("/fetchUsers", async (req, res) => {` but it says Cannot GET /users??

Comment: can you post your code somewhere ?  of client and server like in (https://codeshare.io/)

Comment: if I push the code to a repo and share the repo with you, will that help??

Comment: OKay I'll try. post

Comment: ok here it is: https://github.com/RichMatthews/react-boilerplate/tree/fetch-js. you are on the correct branch (fetch-js). follow me readme2.md for setup instructions. post if any probs

Comment: sorry just pushed now

Comment: just wondering if you're getting on alright and if you a) had something or b) needed anything else from me

Comment: Oops I forgot to reply. I had checked the repo. There is a lot of changes required, you aren't using router functionality properly and by looking at your code I guess you have more to understand about server/client communication. There is lot of improvement required. I'm sorry but correcting everything would require a lot of time and I'm busy as of now.

Comment: I dont think that's entirely true. they way i am rendering the client is correct. react router needs changing minimally. and yeh i do have stuff to learn about server/client relationship but that was my question...but thanks for trying

Comment: I'm sorry I'm busy with a major project and that's why I'm always here, but please refer this https://medium.com/@patriciolpezjuri/using-create-react-app-with-react-router-express-js-8fa658bf892d

Comment: doesn't use react-router v4